# My custom template for my content type won't work in Drupal 7 - Bootstrap Theme

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, templates, drupal-7

I am using bootstrap theme on Drupal 7. My subtheme has some templates that have overwritten certain pages.

I am trying to make a template specifically for one of my content types:

Spokesmodel Page (Machine name: spokesmodel_page)

I have a template named 
**page--spokesmodel_page.tpl.php** but for some reason it's not showing up. I've cleared the cache and written a line of code for testing to see if it works but it's getting the template from **page.tpl.php**

Is there something else I need to do for this to work or should it automatically start working? I've made templates for certain nodes and they work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying node.tpl.php from the parent theme into the child theme and re-naming that according to naming conventions here https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

i.e. node--spokesmodel.tpl.php

Comment: The Bootstrap parent theme doesn't have a node.tpl.php included in its files though. It only has html.tpl.php

Comment: So apparently bootstrap uses the node.tpl.php from the module "node" that comes default with drupal.
I copied that and pasted it into my templates in my subtheme.. renamed it the way you said and it worked!! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The page tpl is not what you're looking for. Assuming the content you have is a basic page, the way to override the template is to use node--page.tpl.php.

You'll have to check if the current page is the one you want and then do the changes you require as this tpl is used by all content of type page.

Comment: I was thinking the same but the Bootstrap theme doesn't have a template called node--page.tpl.php , Should I rename the page.tpl.php node--page.tpl.php on the subtheme templates folder?

Comment: You need to use the node.tpl.php one. That's the generic one being used for all nodes. If you want to override it for just a specific type of nodes, then you just copy it and name it using that name convention: node--[content type name].tpl.php

Comment: I tried that but there is no node.tpl.php included in the Bootstrap parent template theme.

Comment: It's not from the bootstrap theme - themes don't need to provide tpls for everything. You can find it on the node module on modules/node/node.tpl.php.